# How to remove duplicates from a string

Tags: c

Good evening people,

I'm trying to delete duplicated letters from a string. My loop doesn't work correctly. My string is **"ABCBDE"**, I want to print **"ABCDE"**, instead it prints **"ABCEDD"**. The order actually doesn't matter, but I need every letter to be printed only once. Anyone sees a mistake in my code?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[] = "ABCBDE";

    printf("Available: %s\n", str1);

int len1 = strlen(str1);

int i = 0;
int j;
for(i; i < len1; i++){
    for(j = i+1; j < len1+1; j++){

        if (str1[i] == str1[j]) {  // remove duplicated letter
           str1 [j] = str1 [len1 - 1];  // replace with last
           len1 --;               // cut last
        }
    }
}

printf("Available: %s\n", str1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @xing Oh! Fantastic, thank you very much! I appreciate your help ;)

Comment: @xing Tried it with `lrearaor`, and it didn't work. https://repl.it/Nkba/0

Comment: You have a problem with your algorithm. Try to work out step by step what happens not only in code, but with your algorithm steps. Then work on your code.

Comment: `j < len1+1` is definitely one too far.

Comment: @jwdonahue Unfortunately your suspicion proved correct guys, now I revealed it actually still doesn't work flawlessly. When the string is "PPBPPPPBOLOOOO", it prints "POBOL". Unpleasant sticky situation. :-/

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind your code is almost correct actually. The key is to understand that `j` is merely the index of the current character, and copying `j+N` to `j` will result in the same string in cases like `AAA`. What you need to do is invert your `if` condition and add a variable to keep track of where to copy a non-duplicate character. Here's some code to get you started:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
    // Index var used to track where to copy non-duplicate characters.
    int di = i+1;

    for (int j = di; j < len1+1; j++) {
        if (str1[i] != str1[j]) {

            /*
            Replace this comment block with your code.
            */

        }
    }
}
```

Hints:

- If the character at `j` isn't a duplicate of the character at `i`, we can copy the character at `j` to replace the character at `di`.
- `di` increments after every copy is done.
- 2 lines of code.
- If you're having trouble, try to walk through each line of your code with small strings like the ones in the list below. Step by step. On paper if necessary.

  ```
  Start => End
  A     => A
  AA    => A
  AAA   => A
  AB    => AB
  AAB   => AB
  ABA   => AB
  ABB   => AB
  ABC   => ABC
  ```

Comment: In the second for loop, `j < len1+1;` seems to be an error.

Comment: @jwdonahue Not an error. It's required to move the terminating null byte at the end of the string.